# MongoDB find: explain("executionStats").executionStats.nReturned faster than count()

Tags: mongodb

Just noticed that the execution time for count() is much slower than explain("executionStats").executionStats.nReturned which also returns the executed documents count. Can anybody explain what is going on? Here are few examples:

```
// Query1: returns incorrect size() 

        db.test.tourArrivals.find({"tour.stops.locationId":locationId}).max({"scheduleInfo.stopSchedules.lastETAResult":"2016-05-04T15:29:37.9960000+02:00"}).min({"scheduleInfo.stopSchedules.lastETAResult": "2016-05-04T15:29:10.8910000+02:00"}).size();

// Query2: returns correct count     

    db.test.tourArrivals.find({"tour.stops.locationId":locationId}).max({"scheduleInfo.stopSchedules.lastETAResult":"2016-05-04T15:29:37.9960000+02:00"}).min({"scheduleInfo.stopSchedules.lastETAResult": "2016-05-04T15:29:10.8910000+02:00"}).explain("executionStats").executionStats.nReturned;

// Query3: Correct count but slower than Query4
db.test.tourArrivals.find({$and: [
        {"scheduleInfo.stopSchedules.lastETAResult":{$gte: "2016-05-04T15:29:10.8910000+02:00"}},
        {"scheduleInfo.stopSchedules.lastETAResult":{$lte: "2016-05-04T15:29:37.9960000+02:00"}},
        {"tour.stops.locationId":locationId}
]}).count();

// Query4: Correct count but faster than Query3
db.test.tourArrivals.find({$and: [
        {"scheduleInfo.stopSchedules.lastETAResult":{$gte: "2016-05-04T15:29:10.8910000+02:00"}},
        {"scheduleInfo.stopSchedules.lastETAResult":{$lte: "2016-05-04T15:29:37.9960000+02:00"}},
        {"tour.stops.locationId":locationId}
]}).explain("executionStats").executionStats.nReturned;
```

With first 2 queries, although with explain() I do see that correct count of documents were executed, the ouput with count() or size() is the count of all documents in the collection.

Query4 is much faster than query3, and I can't explain why?

I have the lastETAResult field indexed.

Here are the exection times for all queries:

```
// 10.05.2016 18:31:35
// Command #3:
// db.test.tourArrivals.find({"tour.stops.locationId":locationId}).max({"scheduleInfo.stopSchedules.lastETAResult":"2016-05-04T15:29:37.9960000+02:00"}).min({"scheduleInfo.stopSchedules.lastETAResult": "2016-05-04T15:29:10.8910000+02:00"}).size();
// Execution time: 0,1s
// Result:
13629

// 10.05.2016 18:31:35
// Command #4:
// db.test.tourArrivals.find({"tour.stops.locationId":locationId}).max({"scheduleInfo.stopSchedules.lastETAResult":"2016-05-04T15:29:37.9960000+02:00"}).min({"scheduleInfo.stopSchedules.lastETAResult": "2016-05-04T15:29:10.8910000+02:00"}).explain("executionStats").executionStats.nReturned;
// Execution time: 0,3s
// Result:
4638

// 10.05.2016 18:31:36
// Command #5:
// db.test.tourArrivals.find({$and: [
// {"scheduleInfo.stopSchedules.lastETAResult":{$gte: "2016-05-04T15:29:10.8910000+02:00"}},
// {"scheduleInfo.stopSchedules.lastETAResult":{$lte: "2016-05-04T15:29:37.9960000+02:00"}},
// {"tour.stops.locationId":locationId}
// ]}).count();
// Execution time: 0,8s
// Result:
4639

// 10.05.2016 18:31:36
// Command #6:
// db.test.tourArrivals.find({$and: [
// {"scheduleInfo.stopSchedules.lastETAResult":{$gte: "2016-05-04T15:29:10.8910000+02:00"}},
// {"scheduleInfo.stopSchedules.lastETAResult":{$lte: "2016-05-04T15:29:37.9960000+02:00"}},
// {"tour.stops.locationId":locationId}
// ]}).explain("executionStats").executionStats.nReturned;
// Execution time: 0,5s
// Result:
4639
```

Comment: Any updates on this question would be greatly appreciated. We are running MongoDB 3.0.12 (Wired Tiger) and are experiencing the same performance issues with count().

Comment: Same here running mongo 3.2.10 w/WiredTiger